# Python. Озвучка текста на русском языке

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтезатор-речи

Я написал код для таймера с озвучкой каждой секунды на пайтоне, вот код

```
import time
for i in (list(range(11))[::-1]):
    speech=str(i)
    call(["espeak",speech])
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

не нравится мне то что голос железный и речь английская
можно сделать озвучку русской и более плавной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтезаторы речи сейчас не очень развиты. Могу посоветовать Yandex SpeechKit (https://cloud.yandex.ru/services/speechkit). Они предоставляют мультиязычную многоголосую озвучку текста.

Плюсы:

- качество озвучки;
- широкий выбор голосов;
- достойное звучание (по крайней мере, на английском и русском языках);
- выбор эмоций;
- выбор скорости диктовки.

Минусы:

- зависимость приложения от наличия сети;
- стоимость - сервис далеко не бесплатный.

Comment: как установить его на пайтон?

Comment: @Igorok через реквесты.

Comment: существуют ли другие синтезаторы речи под пайтон?

Comment: Синтез речи - операция, требующая больших вычислительных мощностей и большого количества данных для обучения. Обычно эта функция поставляется облачными сервисами (есть ещё Google Cloud, например).
А так почитайте статью: https://geekbrains.ru/posts/tts_python

Answer (score 2):

Из синтезаторов я пробовал яндекс speechkit и rhvoice.

Спитчкит звучит лучше, но он платный. Если нужно регулярно озвучивать что-то то, лучше использовать https://github.com/RHVoice/RHVoice , качество вполне хорошее.

RHVoice - есть в виде библиотеки, или в виде отдельного файла. На питоне быстрее всего вызывать внешний бинарник с нужными параметрами.

Послушать звучание rhvoice можно вот [тут](https://voxworker.com/ru).